# How to make view's width relative properly

Tags: java, android, user-interface, layout, android-widget

a want to make create a view inside a vertical `LinearLayout` which would take 2/3 of availible place in the row. I know i can use two 'Space' widgets on both sides of it with setted weight, but is this the right way to do it? Or should i create multiple layouts for different screens, but does it really worth it? I would really like to know what is a proper way of doing this.

Comment: Try to learn about android:weightsum and android:weight in android. You will find your answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should use the `android:layout_weight`in your xml file.
This attibute works with percentage, for exemple:
You want to occupy 2/3 of the screen with a view, so

```
<View1
...
android:weight="2"
.../>
<View2
...
android:weight="1"
.../>
```

The sum of weights is 3, 2 is 66% of 3, and 1 is 33%. So, View1 will occupy 66%(== 2/3) of the screen and View2 will ocupy 1/3(== 1/3).

Comment: Thanks, i forgot i can use layout_gravity to align center the view.